# My code dont see a whille loop in C (with a getchar function)

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

My program doesnt see the while loop and i cant enter my stiring to c variable

i want to enter a string. if a char in this string will be a number he will stay as a number if he doesnt be a number he will change to char **'num'** place farther in **ascii** code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

    int num;
    char c;

    printf("Enter number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter a string : \n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c + num);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an **`int`**. This is important when you compare to `EOF` which you always should do. Secondly, please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. If you do you will probably be surprised to see the first character that you read. Or maybe not, if you think about the `Enter` key you probably pressed to end the integer input, and what character it might add to the input buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With both `scanf()` and `getchar()`, you generally have to press the [return] key after the desired key. Both the desired key, and the return key, are (usually) placed in the stdin stream. The question code neglected to take this in consideration.  Hence, the first desired key was read by `scanf()` and stored in `num`, but left the return key `'\n'` in the buffer; which was then later read by the `getchar()` and stored in `c`. Hence the loop exit criteria was satisfied, and the program terminated.

Somehow, the code, to be functional, must read the unwanted return key `'\n'` left behind by the call to `scanf();` and perhaps also for the `getchar()`.

Perhaps something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int c;
    char cr[2];
    printf("Enter number: \n");
    scanf("%d%1[\n]", &num, cr);  // Reads %d into num, and garbage '\n' into cr.
    printf("Enter a string : \n");
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(isdigit(c))
            putchar(c);
        else
            putchar(c + num);
        getchar(); // Reads garbage '\n' from previous getchar()
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```